# disable Strict Origin Policy on Geckodriver Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, automation, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

```
profile.set_preference("security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy", False)
```

Is this still work with Geckodriver to disable Strict Origin Policy?
If yes, how can check if it is disabled!?